# Get SMS Messages from SIM card

Tags: android, sms

I want to save the SMS I have on my old Samsung SGH-D500. Since the software for it doesn't save the time for exported messages, I copied messages to the SIM card and backuped them on Android using the following code:

```
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String text = "";
    for(String name : c.getColumnNames()){
        text += name+"\t";
    }
    text += "\n";
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount(); i++){
            text += c.getString(i)+"\t";
        }
        text += "\n";
    }
    Log.d("sms", text);
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(root.canWrite()){
        File export = new File(root, "sms.txt");
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(export));
            bw.write(text);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The first problem is that it only gets the messages that are on the phone. So I have to copy each message (there's no copy all) to the phone first.
The second problem is that Android doesn't even recognize sent messages I put on the SIM card (SIM card is full but Android shows nothing).

I looked into the [Sim Toolkit](http://source.android.com/porting/stk.html), but didn't really know where to start.
Isn't there something like "content://icc/adn" (contacts) just for SMS?

Thanks
Ralf

Comment: Did you manage to get Android to recognize the sent messages on the SIM? Is there any app that can do this. (I can only get the received SMSs from the SIM..., the sent ones are visible when using the SIM with a 'dumb' cellphone.)

Answer (score -1):

I played around with the sms api a long time ago. I don't have the code that retrieved all messages but I found some code that added a message to the sent messages list

`ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", number);
            values.put("body", message);
            getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"),values);`

From memory I think content://sms/inbox retrieves all messages in inbox. I can't comment whether that gets messages both on the phone and on the sim. I use the following software to send messages through my phone from my computer http://www.fjsoft.at/en/. It also shows all text messages and allows you to export them. Again i'm not sure if this is messages on the phone or sim or both. But it's worth a try and is a nice piece of software.